# Splitting columns of a mixed dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

Have a dataframe df:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df=pd.DataFrame(np.array([('x', 'y')] + [('y', 'x')] + 
                         list([0, np.nan]*2)), columns=['Col'])
df
```

How can df be split into two columns as follows?:

```
   Col1 Col2
0   x   y
1   y   x
2   0   0
3   NaN NaN
4   0   0
5   NaN NaN
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `list comprehension` with convert scalars to tuples:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame([x if isinstance(x, tuple) else (x,x) for x in df['Col']], 
                   columns=['Col1','Col2'])
print (df1)
  Col1 Col2
0    x    y
1    y    x
2    0    0
3  NaN  NaN
4    0    0
5  NaN  NaN
```

More general solution:

```
lens = int(df['Col'].str.len().max())
df1 = pd.DataFrame([x if isinstance(x, tuple) else [x] * lens for x in df['Col']])
```

Another solution, slowier in large data:

```
df1 = df['Col'].apply(pd.Series).ffill(axis=1)
```

**Performance**:

```
df = pd.concat([df] * 1000, ignore_index=True)

In [51]: %%timeit
    ...: df1 = pd.DataFrame([x if isinstance(x, tuple) else (x,x) for x in df['Col']], 
    ...:                    columns=['Col1','Col2'])
    ...: 
2.42 ms ± 45.1 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)

In [52]: %%timeit
    ...: df['Col'].apply(pd.Series).ffill(axis=1)
    ...: 
1 s ± 23.2 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

#coldspeed solution
In [53]: %%timeit
    ...: v = pd.to_numeric(df.Col, errors='coerce')
    ...: pd.DataFrame({
    ...:     'Col1': v.fillna(df.Col.str[0]), 
    ...:     'Col2': v.fillna(df.Col.str[-1])})
    ...: 
15.8 ms ± 472 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
```

Comment: Thanks for the timings, but I didn't see where OP says performance is important. :)

Comment: And how can the fast solution generalise to multiple columns?

Comment: @coldspeed - check edit. Btw, timing was mainly for curious how is `apply(pd.Series)` slowier like list comprehension

Comment: Thanks, +1ed the answer

Comment: This was an awesome approach to handle empty lists `[]` in list comprehension. Was struggling to fill the empty lists - so that the length of the list did not change. Kudos to @jezreal and @coldspeed !

Answer (score 2):

A nice, concise solution is to use [`pd.to_numeric`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.to_numeric.html) to convert non-numeric data to NaN, and then [`fillna`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.fillna.html).

```
v = pd.to_numeric(df.Col, errors='coerce')
pd.DataFrame({
    'Col1': v.fillna(df.Col.str[0]), 
    'Col2': v.fillna(df.Col.str[-1])})

  Col1 Col2
0    x    y
1    y    x
2    0    0
3  NaN  NaN
4    0    0
5  NaN  NaN
```

Solution, for multiple possible columns:

```
pd.DataFrame({
    f'Col{i+1}': v.fillna(df.Col.str[i]) 
    for i in range(int(df.Col.str.len().max()))})

  Col1 Col2
0    x    y
1    y    x
2    0    0
3  NaN  NaN
4    0    0
5  NaN  NaN
```